# Add Title or Title Tag to url path

Tags: django, url, django-views

I'm hoping somebody can help me with this issue. Im having trouble adding my page/ article title to the url path. I've tried a number of ways can't seem to get it. If anyone could help that would be great.

My current Url path is "https://stackoverflow.com/article/1"

Would like it to be "https://stackoverflow.com/article/1/example-question-help", or some variation of that.

Below you can find how my views and url files are set up.

```
<a href="{% url 'article-detail' post.pk %}"
```

```
 path('article/<int:pk>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),'
```

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'article_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if stuff.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        return context
```

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='none')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
    # body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')
```

Comment: Share your `Post` model...

Comment: I upgraded my original post. The post model is included.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your model has a slug field, called `slug`, which it looks like it may given your request, you'd change things like this;

```
path('article/<slug:slug>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),'
```

Django will then do the rest because `SingleObjectMixin` which is used by `DetailView` looks at the URL first for a primary key, then for a slug.

So this will give you URLs that look like;

`https://stackoverflow.com/article/example-question-help`

Comment: Thanks for answering! My model currently doesn't have a slug field. Is there a way to do it without one?

Comment: Not really. You could try to make your path something like `'article/<int:pk>/<str:title>/'` and then whenever you build the URLs you'd have to use the `slugify()` utility function to create a URL friendly version of the title. I'd advise against that. You'd be better adding a slug field and populating it for all existing objects by calling `slugify()` with the title value.

Comment: Would I have to change this line, "stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])". I'm currently met with a a 404 error after implementing <slug:slug>

Comment: It seems to be an issue with my page reference "<a href="{% url 'article-detail' post.pk %}". I tried to add |slugify instead, but that doesn't seem to work. Is there anything else I can potentially try?

Comment: @Mak3232 Try to either pass the value via the context or use the `{% with %}` template tag to set the slugified value.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a path that includes both the primary key and the slug:

```
path(
    'article/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/',
    ArticleDetailView.as_view(),
    name='article-detail',
),
```

This will automatically filter the item properly. In the link you then pass both the primary key and slug:

```
<a href="{% url 'article-detail' post.pk post.slug %}">
```

You can boost efficiency by determining the number of likes and whether the object is liked all in the same queryset with an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.db.models import Count, Exists, OuterRef


class ArticleDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'article_detail.html'
    queryset = Post.objects.annotate(total_likes=Count('likes'))

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            is_liked=Exists(
                Post.likes.through.objects.filter(
                    post_id=OuterRef('pk'), user=request.user
                )
            )
        )

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(
            *args, **kwargs, cat_menu=Category.objects.all()
        )
```

In the modeling, you might want to work with an [**`AutoSlugField`** <sup>[readthedocs.io]</sup>](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#autoslug.fields.AutoSlugField) from the [**`django-autoslug`** package <sup>[readthedocs.io]</sup>](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to automatically slugify. Otherwise you will have to do this yourself. It also makes not much sense that the slug field is NULLable: normally a record will *always* have a slug. You thus might want to refactor the model to:

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
from django.conf import settings


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='none')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='liked_posts'
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).